# Why can't we use C-strings as SELs?

Tags: objective-c, methods, selector, objective-c-runtime

So, I've been messing around with the objc-runtime again (surprise surprise), and I found an interesting block of code [here](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.11/runtime/objc-sel.mm):

```
const char *sel_getName(SEL sel) {
#if SUPPORT_IGNORED_SELECTOR_CONSTANT
    if ((uintptr_t)sel == kIgnore) return "<ignored selector>";
#endif
    return sel ? (const char *)sel : "<null selector>";
}
```

So, what this tells me is that a `SEL` is equivalent to a C-string, in every mannerism. Doing a hex dump of the first 16 bytes of SEL that contains `@selector(addObject:)` gives the following:

> 61 64 64 4F 62 6A 65 63 74 3A 00 00 00 00 00 00

Which is equal to the C-string `addObject:`.

With that said, why does this code crash when I use the C-string as the selector?

```
SEL normalSEL  = @selector(addObject:);
SEL cStringSEL = (SEL) "addObject:";

NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];

[arr performSelector:normalSEL withObject:@"3"];
[arr performSelector:cStringSEL withObject:@"4"];

NSLog(@"%@", arr);
```

As far as I can tell, the contents of the selectors are the same, so why the crash on the second one with the following error message?

> `***` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
>       reason: '-[__NSArrayM addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
>       0x101918720' `***`

Comment: Note that you can use `sel_registerName()` to turn a C string into a blessed SEL (it basically uniques the string behind the scenes to preserve subsequent pointer identity).   Note also that you should never directly rely on an SEL being a `char*`.  It probably always will be, but that doesn't make the assumption correct.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Selectors are interned C strings and are compared by their address, not their contents. The string contents is only used for converting to/from an external string representation. Interning is done to improve performance--when the runtime is looking up the method implementation that matches a selector it can compare the selector pointers directly instead of dereferencing each pointer and comparing the characters.

Comment: Hmm... after looking into `__sel_registerName` I believe that you are correct. Still, I wonder how much of a performance difference there really would be...

Comment: This is also strongly implied by the string/selector API; see the docs for [`NSSelectorFromString()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIEICGB) and its connection to `sel_registerName()`.

Comment: objc_msgSend runs in around 8 cycles these days. Not a lot of room for a strcmp() in there ;)